# Регялярное выражение, проверка слов на уникальность

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть следущая задачка, есть строка которая может содержать ограниченный набор слов, для примера: apple, banana, orange- слова разделены точкой запятой. Дополнительно наложено ограничение, что каждое слово должно встречать один раз.

Хотелось бы сделать это с помощью реглярки.
То есть мне надо чтоб:

- проверку проходили строка "banana;apple;" или "banana;apple;orange;"
- но не проходили проверку строки вида "banana;apple;apple;"(2 вхождение apple;) или "banana;apple;orange;banana;apple;orange;"(тут каждое слово дублируется два раза)

Регулряное выражение, которое проверяет что ничего кроме нет, достаточно простое:
^((apple|banana|orange);)+$

А вот как обеспичить проверку на то что каждое слово входит один раз, я вот не знаю.
Может, поскажет кто что-то дельное, ну или скаежт что эта проблема не разрешима на уровне регулярных выражений, тоже буду благодарен.

ЗЫ я конечо могу написать код который это проверяет, но честно говоря не хочется код плодить.

Comment: уточните язык в котором требуется решение задачи.

Comment: [`^(?!.*?(?:^|;)((?:apple|banana|orange))(?=;|$).*;\1(?:;|$))(?:(?:apple|banana|orange);)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/1GyEtt/1/)

Comment: Можно немного упростить выражение: https://regex101.com/r/1GyEtt/3

Comment: Или так: https://regex101.com/r/1GyEtt/5

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, что именно надо в итоге получить, но когда-то давно у меня была задача удалить из строки повторяющиеся слова. Думаю из этого можно получить искомое.

Сама регулярка `(\b[\pL0-9]++\b)(?=.*?\b\1\b)` 
[тут можно потестить](https://regex101.com/r/3hEG2K/1)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
В итоге мне нужно получить регулярку, с помощью которая матчит строку: apple; banana;
И не матчит строку: apple; apple; banana;(так как тут два вхождения  последовательности "apple;").

Comment: Я чуть позже поработаю над вашим регэкспом думаю он мне поможет.